# python nsolve/solve Backward (Implicit) Euler method

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to code the Implicit Euler method:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sp.init_printing(use_latex=True)

def ImplicitEulerMethod(fp1, fp2, x10, x20, h, t0, tmax):
    n = int((tmax - t0)/h + 1)
    x1table = [0 for i in range(n)]
    x2table = [0 for i in range(n)]
    x1table[0] = x10
    x2table[0] = x20
    x1 = sp.symbols('x1')
    x2 = sp.symbols('x2')
    for i in range(1,n):
        s1 = sp.nsolve(x1 - x1table[i - 1] - h*fp1(x1, x2, t0 + i*h), (x1,x2), (x1table[i - 1], x2table[i - 1]))
        x1table[i] = s1
        s2 = sp.nsolve(x2 - x2table[i - 1] - h*fp2(x1, x2, t0 + i*h), (x1,x2), (x1table[i - 1],x2table[i - 1]))
        x2table[i] = s2
    Data = [[t0 + i*h, x1table[i], x2table[i]] for i in range(n)] 
    return Data

x = sp.Function('x')
t = sp.symbols('t')
def fp1(x, y, t): return x - x*y
def fp2(x, y, t): return x*y - y
Data = ImplicitEulerMethod(fp1, fp2, 4, -2, 1, 0, 50)
plt.scatter([point[0] for point in Data],[point[1] for point in Data])
plt.xlabel("Time"); plt.ylabel("Love")
plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

Here is the error message:

```py
C:\Usefcs\pc\Downloads>python cau_4.py Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pc\Downloads\cau_4.py", line 26, in <module>
Data = ImplicitEulerMethod(fpi, fp2, 4, -2, 1, 0, 50)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\pc\Downloads\cau_4.py", line 15, in ImplicitEulerMethod
si = sp.nsolve(xl - xltable[i - 1] - h*fpl(xl, x2, t0 + i*h), (xl,x2), (xltable[i - 1], x2table[i-l]))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sympy\utilities\decorator.py", line 88, in func_wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 2970, in n solve
raise ValueError(filldedent('''
ValueError:
expected a one-dimensional and numerical function
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please, edit the question and copy the code in textual form!

Comment: When using nsolve there must be as many equations as unknowns. Although your *system* has 2 equations and 2 unknowns, you are passing the equations one at a time so there is 1 equation and 2 unknowns. When the question is open I can paste what the code inside the loop should look like, but you may be able to correct it with this hint: `s1, s2 = nsolve([eq1, eq2], (x1, x2), (x1table[i - 1], x2table[i - 1]))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed `nsolve` a single equation in two unknowns. It cannot give a single numerical answer for that case. Instead, you should pass the two equations at once to get the two simultaneous solutions: your loop interior should look like the following.

```py
        s1,s2 = sp.nsolve(
            [x1 - x1table[i - 1] - h*fp1(x1, x2, t0 + i*h),
             x2 - x2table[i - 1] - h*fp2(x1, x2, t0 + i*h)],
            (x1, x2),
            (x1table[i - 1], x2table[i - 1]))
        x1table[i] = s1
        x2table[i] = s2
```